# Using JExcelAPI with Android gets NoClassDefFoundError at runtime for jxl.write.label

Tags: android, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror, jxl, jexcelapi

I am developing an Android app for 4.1.2 on Netbeans 7.3 using the NBAndroid plugin.  I downloaded and compiled the JExcelAPI, and pulled the jxl.jar file into my "libs" folder. My app compiles fine and runs fine, until I try to instantiate a Label object.  Then the program gives that irritating "Unforunately, FinanceApp has stopped."  When I check the LogCat, it tells me that the error was primarily caused by a NoClassDefFoundError pertaining to jxl.write.Label (as you can see in the snippet below).  I don't know what the problem is.  I have looked around and I have made sure that the folder I put the jxl.jar file in was named "libs" not "lib."  I've updated everything, from the Android SDK to Netbeans to jxl.jar (by re-compiling it).  The error doesn't change.

Thanks in advance for the help!

-John

The LogCat snippet:

```
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3598)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17036)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3593)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  jxl.write.Label
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.<package-name>.financeapp.TransactionActivity.addTransaction(TransactionActivity.java:86)
06-10 12:11:44.037 10704 10704 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 14 more
```

Comment: did you add the jar file to the build path?
right click on it, and "add to build path"
then clean project, and run

Comment: Would that work for NetBeans?  It doesn't seem to.